# In 2019, how do i connect Heroku app to GoDaddy DNS?

Tags: heroku, dns

I am trying to connect my webapp to domain.

Heroku:

[image: heroku settings]

GoDaddy:

[image]

Searched high and low - doesn't seem to be any clear documentation with examples for settings anywhere. Bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot there is A record which needs to be removed.

I think you are pointing via cname which can be considered as an alternate option but this is not possible in Godaddy to point naked/root domain ([link](https://help.heroku.com/NH44MODG/my-root-domain-isn-t-working-what-s-wrong)), so would recommend you to add a addon on heroku name pointDNS and copy all the records from GoDaddy to pointDNS.Please try to follow below mentioned steps

1. Add the domain to your heroku app => heroku domains:add domainname
2. Go to resources-> add `PointDNS` addon,

a.Verify by clicking on pointDNS

b.Copy all NS records from wix to pointDNS

c.Update NS issued by pointDNS (dns8.pointhq.com,dns12.pointhq.com) in godaddy

Comment: As GoDaddy doesn't allow naked domain pointing so you need to use a service like pointDNS.

Comment: I've been doing this for years but it is no longer a valid answer. godaddy requires ip addresses with nameservers now.  Just spent a half hour on the phone with godaddy and it looks like old websites will be grandfathered in but godaddy will no longer be compatible with heroku in the future (unless someone knows a hack)

Comment: @Philip7899: Just updated the NS and godaddy didn't asked for any IP.

Comment: you are right.  After sspending even more time with godaddy on the phone, it turns out they have very specific rules if you do not use a popular toplevel domain. so if youre using (.com/.co/.io/etc....) you're probably fine.  We were using .it which caused all sorts of problems.